# Vuetify - Can't drag and drop all-day events in monthly view

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

With **vuetify** and its v-calendar only not-daily events can be dragged when you are in week and day view (in monthly view not work at all).
I would like to move daily events (during entire day, not from 00:01 to 23:59) to another day when you are in **month view** (mainly) or in week view

Template (only related parts):

```
        <v-calendar
          ref="calendar"
          v-model="value"
          :weekdays="weekday"
          :type="type"
          :events="events"
          :event-overlap-mode="mode"
          :event-overlap-threshold="30"
          :event-color="getEventColor"
          @change="getEvents"
          @click:event="showEvent"
          @mousedown:event="startDrag"
          @mousedown:time="startTime"
          @mousemove:time="mouseMove"
          @mouseup:time="endDrag"
          @mouseleave.native="cancelDrag"
        >
          <template #event="{ event, timed, eventSummary }">
            <div class="v-event-draggable" v-html="eventSummary()" />
            <div
              v-if="timed"
              class="v-event-drag-bottom"
              @mousedown.stop="extendBottom(event)"
            />
          </template>
        </v-calendar>
```

script (only related functions):

```
    startDrag({ event, timed }) {
      if (event && timed) {
        this.dragEvent = event;
        this.dragTime = null;
        this.extendOriginal = null;
      }
    },
    startTime(tms) {
      const mouse = this.toTime(tms);

      if (this.dragEvent && this.dragTime === null) {
        const start = this.dragEvent.start;

        this.dragTime = mouse - start;
      } else {
        this.createStart = this.roundTime(mouse);
        this.createEvent = {
          name: `Event #${this.events.length}`,
          color: this.rndElement(this.colors),
          start: this.createStart,
          end: this.createStart,
          timed: true
        };

        this.events.push(this.createEvent);
      }
    },
    mouseMove(tms) {
      const mouse = this.toTime(tms);

      if (this.dragEvent && this.dragTime !== null) {
        const start = this.dragEvent.start;
        const end = this.dragEvent.end;
        const duration = end - start;
        const newStartTime = mouse - this.dragTime;
        const newStart = this.roundTime(newStartTime);
        const newEnd = newStart + duration;

        this.dragEvent.start = newStart;
        this.dragEvent.end = newEnd;
      } else if (this.createEvent && this.createStart !== null) {
        const mouseRounded = this.roundTime(mouse, false);
        const min = Math.min(mouseRounded, this.createStart);
        const max = Math.max(mouseRounded, this.createStart);

        this.createEvent.start = min;
        this.createEvent.end = max;
      }
    },
    endDrag() {
      this.dragTime = null;
      this.dragEvent = null;
      this.createEvent = null;
      this.createStart = null;
      this.extendOriginal = null;
    },
    cancelDrag() {
      if (this.createEvent) {
        if (this.extendOriginal) {
          this.createEvent.end = this.extendOriginal;
        } else {
          const i = this.events.indexOf(this.createEvent);
          if (i !== -1) {
            this.events.splice(i, 1);
          }
        }
      }

      this.createEvent = null;
      this.createStart = null;
      this.dragTime = null;
      this.dragEvent = null;
    },
  }
};
```

Full Code here: https://codepen.io/iessIsMore/pen/rNGjzpJ

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

mousedown events have to be changed to **day** instead of **time**
I tried to to solve the problem , here is the solution.
[Codepen Link](https://codepen.io/namanitsofficial/pen/mdXayBm)

```
<div id="app">
<v-app id="inspire">
<v-row class="fill-height">
  <v-col>
    <v-sheet height="600">
      <v-calendar
        ref="calendar"
        v-model="value"
        color="primary"
        type="4day"
        :events="events"
        :event-color="getEventColor"
        :event-ripple="false"
        @change="getEvents"
        @mousedown:event="startDrag"
        @mousedown:day="startTime"
        @mousemove:day="mouseMove"
        @mouseup:day="endDrag"
        @mouseleave.native="cancelDrag"
      >
        <template v-slot:event="{ event, timed, eventSummary }">
          <div
            class="v-event-draggable"
            v-html="eventSummary()"
          ></div>
          <div
            v-if="!timed"
          ></div>
        </template>
      </v-calendar>
    </v-sheet>
  </v-col>
</v-row>
</v-app>
</div>
```

Would like to know the insights of other people regarding my solution.
Thanks.